# docker service + service is down but not know the reason

Tags: systemd, rhel, process, docker, systemctl

we have docker service installed on all or rhel 7.5 machines ( 5 machines )

from some unclear reason we see that docker service is stooped on all machines ( machine are up last 1 year )

this is strange because the docker service is configured with Restart=always , so in case docker service is down ,  then after few seconds it will start automatically , according to the following docker service configuration

```
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```

and full description:

```
more /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
BindsTo=containerd.service
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
```

what I am worry is about some `kill` action as `kill -9` on docker service PID , and maybe this is the case , but on the the hand , no user was login to the machines , so this is very strange
any hint about this ?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: which logs is represented the docker service?

Comment: No offense, but with as much reputation as you have and a position managing infrastructure, you don't know which logs to examine?

Comment: from journalctl >/tmp/file , when looking on file , I cant find the root cause why service stooped

Comment: Most docker containers are setup so that the software logs to stdout or stderr. This is automatically saved by docker and can be viewed with the "docker logs" command. I suggest you read a bit more on google about how to use this command.

Comment: yes but after I start the docker and docker compose I have new ID container ( as docker logs 8cbffb863536 ) , so the previous logs are not appears because the container ID is different